# Pass ReadStream to a POST FORM from file on google cloud storage

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-storage

I am trying to send a POST form including (raw) files and these files are located in a google cloud storage bucket

This code runs in a firebase cloud function - Instead of downloading the storage file to a the cloud function instance and then uploading it via the form (which works), I would like to pass the form the Stream directly

```
async function test() {
 const rp = require('request-promise');
 const path = require('path');
 const { Storage } = require('@google-cloud/storage');
 const storage = new Storage();
 const bucketName = 'xxx';
 const bucket = storage.bucket(bucketName);
 const fileAPath = path.join('aaa', 'bbb.jpg');

 let formData = {
  fileA: bucket.file(fileAPath).createReadStream(),
 };

 return rp({
  uri: uri,
  method: 'POST',
  formData: formData,
 });
}
```

The POST works as intended if we download the file first (to a temp file on the cloud functions instance) and then use `fs.createReadStream(fileAPath_tmp)`

The POST fails (i.e. the end point is not receiving the file in the same way, if at all), when using the code above (no temp download) using `bucket.file(fileAPath).createReadStream()`

Answer (score 1):

Based on the docs for Google File Storage [`createReadStream`](https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/storage/1.3.x/File#createReadStream), you need to use the read stream as if it is an event emitter to populate a buffer to return to the end user. You should be able to use the `.pipe()` method to pipe it directly to the HTTP response, similar to your existing source code.

```
remoteFile.createReadStream()
  .on('error', function(err) {})
  .on('response', function(response) {
    // Server connected and responded with the specified status and headers.
   })
  .on('end', function() {
    // The file is fully downloaded.
  })
  .pipe(.....));
```

Comment: The pipe expects something like a WriteStream as an input. How can I then provide the file's Stream to the POST request's formData?

Comment: I have the same question. How can we make the stream returned by `.pipe()` attach to HTTP response?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get this working using the `form-data` npm package. My example uses `axios` but I'm guessing it will be similar for `request-promise`:

```
import FormData from 'form-data'; // npm install form-data

const uploadFileFromFirebaseStorage = async (bucketName, fileName) => {
   const file = storage.bucket(bucketName).file(fileName);

   const formData = new FormData();
   formData.append('file', file.createReadStream(), fileName);

   const url = 'some-api/upload';
   const headers = { ...getAuthHeaders(), ...formData.getHeaders() };
   return axios.post(url, formData, { headers });
};
```